# Show that $\lambda \cdot z=z+\lambda$ gives an action of $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\tau=x+i y \in \mathbb{C}, x, y>0$. Show that $\lambda \cdot z=z+\lambda$ gives an action of $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{C}$. What does the decomposition into subclasses look like?

My thought's so far (Edit):

To demonstrate that the operation $\lambda \cdot z=z+\lambda$ defines an action of the group $\mathbb{Z}+$ $\tau \mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{C}$, we need to verify the properties of a group action:

1. Well-defined operation: Showing that $ \left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right) \cdot z=\lambda_{1} \cdot\left(\lambda_{2} \cdot z\right)$ for all $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2} \in$ $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C} $.
2. Respects group structure: Demonstrating that $\lambda \cdot(\mu \cdot z)=(\lambda \cdot \mu) \cdot z$ for all $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
3. Trivial action of the neutral element: Showing that $0 \cdot z=z $ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Each coset represents an equivalence class of numbers in the complex plane generated by translations by elements of $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$.

For $\lambda=0$, the coset $0+(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$ is equivalent to the set $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ itself.
For $\lambda=1$, the coset $1+(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})=1+\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$.
For $\lambda=\tau$, the $\operatorname{coset} \tau+(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})=\tau+\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$.

This pattern continues, with each coset representing a translation of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}+$ $\tau \mathbb{Z}$, where $\tau$ determines the direction and $\mathbb{Z}$ determines the spacing in the respective directions.

Are my thought's now right so far?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau\simeq\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R}\tau\simeq\mathbb{R}^2$. Every time you have a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, $H$ acts on $G$ operating on the right.

Comment: What do you mean by your third point, associativity? It is verbatim the same requirement as "identity". Also, your characterisation of cosets is false. For example, $1+\Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z} = 0 + \Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z}$. Play around with this a bit more, and try to consider it geometrically. What does $\Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z}$ look like inside $\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim: Ok - is this right?:
$\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ forms a lattice in the complex plane, which is generated by the integer linear combinations of 1 and $\tau$. The equivalence $1+$ $ \mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}=0+\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ shows that translations within this lattice lead to equivalent point sets.

Comment: Is this AI generated? Why are you being so formal about something that carries almost no information?
It is true that it forms a lattice. Now draw it. Pick up a few examples, try to figure out where the other points of its equivalence class lie (note: the lattice helps). To really appreciate the question, try to find a *fundamental domain*: I.e. a subset of $\Bbb{C}$ such that no two points in the set are equivalent, but every point of $\Bbb{C}$ is equivalent to some point in the set. Hint: you can see it from your drawing of the lattice.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim I'm so formal because that's how it's usually specified ( by us at least) - every step has to be described exactly. But now I still don't understand what the illustration by the drawing brings me - I still have to give a formal proof?

Comment: @Euler007 That's okay. The problem is that your characterization is far from complete. You have not described the subclasses at all. Therefore, I hope a drawing would give you inspiration and insight into the problem.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim: I've edited my new thoughts above - I'm on the right track now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a full answer since it seems you have spent some time thinking about it.

Again, you have correctly shown it is an action. The second part, "...decomposition into subclasses..." is a little vague, but I interpret it as, "what does $\Bbb{C}$ quotiented by the action look like"? This question makes sense, as a group action $G\to \text{Aut}(S)$ induces an equivalence relation on the set $S$ given by $s_1\sim s_2$ if $\exists g\in G$ s.t. $g.z_1=z_2$.

Considering you action, $\phi:\Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z}\to \text{Aut}(\Bbb{C})$, I see two ways of answering this, either by describing how $\Bbb{C}/\phi$ looks like geometrically or comparing it to another well known object, or describe how elements of this quotient looks like.

The latter is not too enlightening, an element $\alpha\in \Bbb{C}/\phi$ is literally $a+\Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z}$ for $a\in \Bbb{C}$, i.e. it is $a$ translated by any $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combination of $1$ and $\tau$. But geometrically, it is a nice picture.
Consider the parallellogram spanned by $1$ and $\tau$ as vectors in $\Bbb{C}$. See the image below for a visual. This will be a *fundamental domain* of the action, i.e. no two points in the parallellogram are equivalent, but every point in $\Bbb{C}$ is equivalent to some point therein. In fact, $\Bbb{C}$ is tiled by translations of this parallellogram (let's call it F), and the translations are exactly $\alpha+F$ for $\alpha\in \Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z}$.

In the picture below, $v_1 = 1$ and $v_2=\tau$.

[image: Fundamental domain of a lattice]

(picture blatantly stolen from the web, found it here: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/615-let-l-lattice-let-f-fundamental-domain-l-exercise-sketches-proof-lim-bronl-vol-br-0-1--q46910782).

Now, there is an obvious bijection between $\Bbb{C}/\phi$ and $F$, and it turns out to be a group isomorphism as well, if you turn $F$ into a group with "pac-man addition", i.e. going up through the top of the parallellogram puts you back at the bottom of the parallellogram, and analogously with the sides (formally, you take the usual sum in $\Bbb{C}$ and then translate it by $\Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z}$ to get an element in the parallellogram).

These two objects are thus one and the same. Also, having this geometric picture is more than just a neat fact. It is also useful in characterising your lattice, and gives you geometric properties of the quotient. As maybe the primary example, it is easy to convince yourself that this is a torus, i.e. a donut.